# Creating controller inside a view angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a controller inside one of my views ..
I have a structure like this

```
index.html
pages > home.html
js > app.js, controllers.js
```

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: '/pages/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
});
```

**controllers.js :**

`angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function(){ ... });`

Everything is working great but is it possible to create another controller inside home.html file ?

I tried this but not working

**home.html :**

```
<div ng-controller="InsiderCtrl">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app.controllers').controller('InsiderCtrl', function(){ ... });
</script>
```

But when I tried using function instead it worked! Can anyone explain me why? Isn't it possible to access the modules inside a view ?

```
<div ng-controller="InsiderCtrl">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function InsiderCtrl() {}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a controller inside if a view?

Comment: In laravel framework you can create packages to reuse, I created one that contains the index page and defines the controllers and all js files so I can't modify these because my modifies will be reverted every time I use `composer update`

Comment: I am also interested in this question.